# elasticsearch search by part of a word

Tags: elasticsearch

Could you help me? There is an ELK cluster (version 5) and through kibana I execute a query for a part of a word using a wildcard, for example, **examp***, but nothing is found. If I search for the whole word **example**, then everything is found. I also have a second ELK cluster and everything is found correctly in the part of the word using wildcard. I don't understand what is the difference between the settings between these two clusters

Comment: what is version ES both cluster?

Comment: Can you please compare index mapping of both index ?